# "mktemp: too few X's in template" if there are two sets of X in file name

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am using Xenial ubuntu. The bash version is `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

I am getting this error **`mktemp: too few X's in template`** when my shell script executes this command `mktemp /tmp/1556580619403-0/duplicate.XXXXXXX.BABj9f0X1bg_work_DADYj9GphRM2_page0_preview.png`

The file name is actually constructed like this in a function

```
myfunction() {
    local filename
    filename=$0
    mktemp /tmp/1556580619403-0/duplicate.XXXXXXX.${filename}
}
```

The second occurrence of `X` is apparently causing the problem.

Is there any switch or other methods (other than replacing the second occurrence of `X` in the file name) that can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mktemp` replaces [the last run of Xs in the template](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/mktemp):

> The final run of ‘X’s in the template will be replaced by alpha-numeric character

The simplest option is to use

```
mktemp "/tmp/1556580619403-0/duplicate.$filename.XXXXXXX"
```

If you really need it to end in the original filename, use the `--suffix` option:

```
mktemp /tmp/1556580619403-0/duplicate.XXXXXXX --suffix ".$filename"
```